# Navigating to the view pager tab from an activity

Tags: android

I am creating an android application which uses viewpager and [PageSlidingTabLibrary](https://github.com/LordZoltan/PagerSlidingTabStrip.Net/wiki/Using-and-customising-PagerSlidingTabStrip.Net).It has 4 tabs and each tab has a list view inside it.when the list view item is clicked a new activity opens and shows the details of the item clicked.The new activity has a back button in action bar to previous activity(ie MainActivity) in which tab view is present.
The problem is if the navigation to other activity is from second tab after comeback to the MainActivity the second tab should be shown but it doesn't happend it will go to the first tab.How can i get it done Help me.

Here is my code

xml layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dip"
    app:pstsDividerColor="#ff1abc9c"
    app:pstsIndicatorColor="#ff1abc9c"
    app:pstsIndicatorHeight="5dp"
    app:pstsDividerPadding="5dp"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
    app:pstsUnderlineColor="#ff1abc9c"
    />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <!--you can put your existing views of your current xml here, so yes your entire xml is now inside this FrameLayout -->
    </FrameLayout>
  </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
  </LinearLayout>
```

and Activity file

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

ViewPager pager;
PagerSlidingTabStrip tabStrip;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    pager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    tabStrip= (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabStrip.setViewPager(pager);
    Log.d("msg","Oncreate in  main activity called");
    if(savedInstanceState!=null)
    {
        onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }


}


public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements PagerSlidingTabStrip.IconTitleProvider
{

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                return "Events";
            case 1:
                return "Users";
            case 2:
                return "Groups";
            case 3:
                return "Settlement";
        }


        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                return new EventFragment();
            case 1:
                return new UserFragment();
            case 2:
                return new GroupFragment();
            case 3:
                return new SettlementFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public int getPageIconResId(int position) {
        switch(position)
        {
            case 0:
                return R.drawable.event;
            case 1:
                return R.drawable.user;
            case 2:
                return R.drawable.group;
            case 3:
                return R.drawable.settlement;
        }


        return 0;
    }
}
}
```

Fragment class

```
public class EventFragment extends ListFragment {

String[] events={"Trip to Goa","Trip to Ooty"};

public EventFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}




@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ListView eventlist=new ListView(getActivity());
    eventlist.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    eventlist.setId(android.R.id.list);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,events);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    return eventlist;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("Tabno",1);

}

@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)     {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);


        Intent expense = new Intent();
        expense.setClass(getActivity(), ExpenseActivity.class);
        startActivity(expense);
        Bundle eventbundle=new Bundle();
        eventbundle.putInt("Tabno",1);
        onSaveInstanceState(eventbundle);


}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your next activity add these codes :

```
 @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                break;

            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

Comment: sorry not device back button.Its Action bar back button

Comment: android.R.id.home is an actionbar back button.

Comment: for that if i need to set "setDisplsyHomeAsUpEnabled" to true

Comment: Yes...you have to set it enabled.

Comment: No , there is no need because you are overriding home button.

Answer (score 1):

Override your device's back button:

```
@Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   finish();
   super.onBackPressed();
 }
```

Comment: sorry not device back button.Its Action bar back button

Answer (score 0):

Just override the back button in your activity details:

```
@Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   finish();
   super.onBackPressed();
 }
```

And it will shows the correct fragment in the viewpager

Comment: sorry not device back button.Its Action bar back button

Comment: then just override the backPressed on your actionBar back button